# Windows 10 cmd shell: exe file on PATH not recognized as external command

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, path

Having launched (in Windows 10) a `cmd.exe` Command shell,
I experience the following problem.

This is the `PATH`:

```
C:\Users\ro> path
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\; C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\; C:\WINDOWS\system32; C:\WINDOWS; C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem; C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; [...]; C:\Program Files\PuTTY\; C:\ProgramFiles_installedByRS;C:\Users\ro\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

`sqlite3.exe` is in the second-to-last directory:

```
C:\Users\ro> dir C:\ProgramFiles_installedByRS\sqlite3.exe
 Il volume nell'unità C non ha etichetta.
 Numero di serie del volume: 4E81-2FDA

 Directory di C:\ProgramFiles_installedByRS

03/07/2017  09:45           729.088 sqlite3.exe
```

> Translation:
>   “Il volume nell'unità C non ha etichetta. / Numero di serie del volume:”
>   is just
>   “The volume in drive C does not have a label. / Volume Serial Number:”

If I launch the command with an explicit full path, it works:

```
C:\Users\ro> C:\ProgramFiles_installedByRS\sqlite3
SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-08 14:26:16
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.

sqlite>
```

If I launch it relying on the environment `PATH`, it doesn't:

```
C:\Users\ro> sqlite3
"sqlite3" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
```

What is the problem?  How do I fix it?

Comment: You can start by removing the spaces directly after a `;` in your `PATH`. That is invalid.